# JQuery does not run in .html file

Tags: jquery, html

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to get my jquery to show on my .html file, but it doesnt run!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(".mainNav a").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".subNav").slideDown('fast').show();
    $(this).parent().hover(function() {}, function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".subNav").slideUp('fast');
    });
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("subHover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("subHover");
});


</script>
```

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Use document.ready for your jquery code. Currently jQuery might be loading later.

Comment: Where is HTML part?  what you exactly trying to achieve? Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){........//your code.....});`

Comment: I'll add the code shortly!

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: Ok, adding it is fairly ugly. Adding $(document).ready(function(){........//your code.....}); isn't working.  It's at http://codepen.io/SalvatoreSantamaria/pen/gWWaJm

Comment: I do get an error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
QuestionThreeNavigation.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at QuestionThreeNavigation.html:6

Comment: Try downloading the jquery file to your local machine and reference that script instead.

Comment: It's alive! I started a fresh document and got it to run. YOU ROCK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure [document is ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) :

```
$(function() {
    //YOUR jQuery CODE GOES HERE
});
```

**OR**

Move your all scripts to the `<body>` of your html.

```
<body>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

    $(".mainNav a").hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".subNav").slideDown('fast').show();
        $(this).parent().hover(function() {}, function() {
            $(this).parent().find(".subNav").slideUp('fast');
        });
    }).hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("subHover");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("subHover");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, adding it is fairly ugly. Adding $(document).ready(function(){........//your code.....}); isn't working. It's at codepen.io/SalvatoreSantamaria/pen/gWWaJm

Comment: Ugly?? And why is that? Your code is not participating in beauty contest, is it :) See the update for atlernative solution.

Comment: In the codepen link you provided dropdown is working fine, what is not working for you?

Comment: hey Lekhnath- the codepen works fine, I'm just trying to get it to work in an  .html file. I still can't get it to work, even after adding the document ready or moving it to the body

Answer (score 0):

2 way you have to fixed

1.add script in head and use

```
<script src="source of jquery"></script>
<script>
$document.ready(function(){

some code jQuery

})
</script>
```

2.add script before </body> tag

```
<script src="source of jquery"></script> 
<script>

enter code here here

</script>
```

this time you don't need $document.ready() anymore

Comment: in way two before tag </body>